# Text Files and Android Application Q

Tags: android, text-files

I am new to Android programming, and I am trying to make an application that will read files from a bluetooth device. I don't need to worry about that right now, since that is the last step I plan to do.

I want to create my own textfile so that I could read fake data from that file and use it to test if my code and function of the application actually work. How would I go about creating this file in Android? And also, how would I also read the text file into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Having a search on google would have found it pretty easy...

Reading a file from sd card:
[How can I read a text file from the SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android)

Creating:
[Android write to sd card folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder)

Answer (score 0):

By the help of string builder you can create a content to write in your file. After that create a stream writer to write file in memory. 
Remember to add permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
I mentioned three steps here. Step by step follow these steps and you will be able to create text file. 
Now again to read this file you have to create a stream reader.

Just google the code for string builder, stream reader, stream writer in java.

If you still have any question or i am missing something, then reply.