# What will be the best strategy to publish content in MS-word file through Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, ms-word

We have lots of content in MS-word files. We would like to publish this through Android and iOS app.
What will be the best strategy to publish content in MS-word file in Android and iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

So it is doc files?

Since there is no api for those if i remember right, because microsoft owns the licensing, you would have to convert them in some way and view them. Probably pdf. Are you planning on saving them locally or on a server?

Comment: Some of them will be embedded in app and some will be downloaded from server.

Comment: then you only need now a way to open/display the content. if all those files contain only text, then you can use this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android  if they also contain pictures etc you will have to have a public intent to open an application that is able to view doc files like described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242306/android-how-to-open-a-doc-extention-file

Comment: Agreed - PDF is likely to cover all your options and display is fairly universal.  This means you should convert your documents to PDF before you ship them within your app.  Alternatively you can have them on a server separately and allow the user to download them on demand (still should be PDF format to make your life easy on the mobile platforms).  That way you can change the content available without changing the deployed app.  Docmosis (I work for this company) has an online service to convert such documents if that's useful.