# Load .docx file in assets folder into webview

Tags: android, webview, doc, android-assets

I have a file "info.docx" placed in Android assets folder. I need to load/display this file in webview. Is it possible?
I tried         `urlWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/info.docx");`
but it displays a blank screen.
Please help.

Comment: Did you try the browsers on your device already for .docx? Or on your pc?

Answer (score 0):

WebView doesn't display Office documents. You can launch an intent for opening a doc file (see [Android how to open a .doc extension file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242306/android-how-to-open-a-doc-extention-file)), but the file itself in this case must reside in some location which is accessible to other apps (the assets of your file are *not* accessible to other apps).