# Showing .DOCX file in android web view using google doc giving error

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

I have to show different type of documents from a remote URL link in my application. I have use Google Doc in a webview like this

```
    private WebView mWvHome = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wv_home);
    mWvHome.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                }
            });
    mWvHome.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                }
            });    
    mWvHome.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    //Pasting a Fixed URL link to the file I am getting this Error.
    mWvHome.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://followitdc.cloudapp.net/FollowitMediaAPIv4/images/bb629006-d930-4fbe-b9ec-91895dc5133c.docx");
```

Here is my Layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/progress" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/progress"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After loading getting this response from google doc.

[image]

File of size less than 2MB in .docx format are loading some file less than 2MB are also not loading. What it the issue? Is it file size issue or Error in file. Because file is working properly in Google Doc online Editor and also on Microsoft Word. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url this will not work in some of android devices.

Comment: what should I do to fix it @MathaN

Comment: If you have backend team tell them to give a link to read a document files. It will be better. I have  done the same for my application.

Comment: They are actually giving a read link. I converting this read link to show in Google Doc view so that I don't have to render the file by my own just using the already build components. 

How you using the read link? like using any library or what to display the documents. I have to read PDF, DOC, DOCX and other file type supported by Google Doc. Any help @MathaN

Comment: I have used this link  
docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url, But it doesn't work. So backend team have created a web app. I have used that app in my WebView to read documents link. It's same as Google doc reader

Comment: Is app is a web base document view which you provide a link and it display the content of the file @MathaN

Comment: String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";  webview.loadUrl("http://domain.com/documentsviewer?url=" + pdf);

Comment: This will only work for pdf and not for docx file. @MathaN

Answer (score 2):

After some struggle i have reached to [this link](https://gist.github.com/izazueta/4961650) in which they have mention "Office Web Apps Viewer" an online app for file extension like ('.ppt' '.pptx' '.doc', '.docx', '.xls', '.xlsx') you just need to provide the online document link in your webview

http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=[OFFICE_FILE_URL]

Google online doc view app does't handle the DOC and DOCX file properly for me and giving the above error I have mention. But after using Office live app for office file extension everything work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), in using `loadDataWithBaseURL`, WebView can access local device files (via 'file' scheme URLs)

> only if baseUrl specifies a scheme other than 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'about' or 'javascript'.

However, as far as I know, WebView currently does not support displaying of office documents. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine.

Please check solution in this SO post - [Android how to open a .doc extention file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242306/android-how-to-open-a-doc-extention-file) and this post in GitHub - [AndroidDocxToHtml](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml) which might help.

Comment: Can you guide for load rtf content with textview @Teyam?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String fileUrl = "https://cs.wmich.edu/elise/courses/cs526/Android-tutorial.docx";               
WebView personalWebView = findViewById(R.id.personalWebView);
personalWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
personalWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + fileUrl);
```

or this:

```
String fileUrl = "https://cs.wmich.edu/elise/courses/cs526/Android-tutorial.docx";
String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+fileUrl+"' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
WebView personalWebView = findViewById(R.id.personalWebView);
personalWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
personalWebView.loadData( doc , "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
url=url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
String newUA= "Chrome/43.0.2357.65 ";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
webView.loadUrl("https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src="+url);
```

Here url is the variable where your file is available.