# Android URL Scheme To Open File From Browser Link?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

On Android (8.0), I'm trying to create a local html file that includes links to some local files that can't be viewed directly by Chrome, like `<a href="relative_path_to_file/file.docx">`.  In a normal web browser (i.e. on a PC), I can click the link and it will open the file in its default viewer. On Android, if I open one of the local html files in Chrome and click one of those links, it directs me to content://nextapp.fx.FileProvider/path_to_file/file.docx, showing "Your file was not found."  I do have an appropriate app installed to view the file (I can open it via a file explorer app).  I would like to understand how I can structure the URLs such that docs of various types (i.e. docx, xlsx, pdf, etc) can be accessed via the links that refer to them - clicking the link should offer to open the file, as it does when accessing the file from a file manager.

- I tried rewriting the links to an absolute path, i.e. "/storage/emulated/0/path/file.docx." The result is the same.
- I tried rewriting the links to "file:///storage/emulated/0/path/file.docx." Chrome just redirects to about:blank.
- I tried opening the html doc with "HTML Viewer" rather than Chrome. The behavior is more or less the same (in the first case it redirects to about:blank, in the second it says "No app available to open link.")

How can I structure the link so it can be clicked & open the referred-to file in appropriate viewer?

Comment: try this question to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242306/android-how-to-open-a-doc-extension-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Related (& I had read that answer previously), but I still couldn't figure out how to structure the url in html per my question (so it offers the available apps for that file type)...

Comment: have you read about interacting html in android in net?

Comment: ...Huh? Are you asking if I've searched online for a solution? Yes, obviously...that's why I'm asking :P

Comment: How does Chrome on Android behave if it just displays the website and not uses the local files?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the question - it isn't actually an offline copy of a website that exists online; it's an html doc I'm creating from scratch, locally. So it's local-only.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers like firefox and opera?

Comment: Edge behaves identically to Chrome.  Firefox didn't appear as an "Open With" option (I guess it didn't identify itself as a handler for .html files), but if I explicitly did Open With in FX Explorer, it said access to the file was denied, I guess because it doesn't know how to request access to storage. Opera didn't appear as an "Open With" option, but if I explicitly Open With w/ FX, tapping the link will download the file to the /Download folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  A working link to open the local file in its default viewer looks like:

```
"intent:///abs/path/to/file.docx#Intent;scheme=file;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;"
```

...With one important caveat: it breaks if there are any "dots" in the path (i.e. I had the files in a .hiddenFolder, which apparently causes Chrome to be unable to figure out the intent link).

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Why not using a WebView in your app?