# How to read from .txt file

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to read the text from a file which is present on server, this file containing the text "hello world" ,now i want to write this text on TextView . i have imported all required packages . thanks in advance

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        try {
            URL updateURL = new URL("http://--------------------/foldername/hello.txt");                
            URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current = 0;
            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                 baf.append((byte)current);
            }


            final String s = new String(baf.toByteArray());     
            ((TextView)tv).setText(s); 





        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2902689/601868

Comment: its just not showing what is written on text file which i present on server , it is not showing any error..but i am not getting the desired resutl

Answer (score 1):

try this function ....

```
 public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        is.close();

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: will you please explain to me how to replace this function with my function because i am getting some error while implementing this function, i am having problem where should i place link to the file which is on server. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 URL url = new URL(urlpath);
 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream((url.openStream()));
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
 String full = "";
 String line;
 while ((line=dis.readLine())!=null) {
     full +=line;               
  }      
bis.close();
dis.close();

((TextView)tv).setText(full);
```