# Modify txt file at server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app that can read, update, delete each line of a `.txt` file

How to access(read, update, delete) `.txt` file directly from the server with android device without having to download the `.txt` file.

This is the link I tried [How to read from .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896312/how-to-read-from-txt-file)
but I got error when I tried it

Comment: Put functionality on the server to read/update/delete the file.  Send commands to that server-side functionality from Android.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't look bad, in fact I will say its just a thing of permissions server side the main problem that you have when you want to access the file. Try giving permissions to the file of Writing and Reading.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Anyway, is there a way to implement in the java?

Comment: @axierjhtjz I try at local server, and it is already has the write and read permission

Comment: Sure. Servlet, JSP, maybe even RMI (I'm less familiar with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to make the changes serverside if you don't want to download the .txt file.

However, since a .txt file usually isn't that big, it should not be a problem to download it, edit it and upload it again using FTP.

Comment: Yeah, the file is not big because only contain text
I will consider to download if there is no other way, thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, please mark it as accepted. Also, if the text files becomes too big, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717165/how-can-i-zip-and-unzip-a-string-using-gzipoutputstream-that-is-compatible-with