# reading a file on android

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to read a file, and I keep getting an error saying ENOENT(no such file or directory).

I made the .txt file on my computer, and then I wanted to use that.  I've tried putting the file in many different places, the assets folder, in data/data/files and I keep getting the error. Can someone help me?

This is the code I have written.

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("permissions.txt");
        DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
        String strLine = null;
        int i =0;
        while((strLine = dataIO.readUTF()) != null){
            i++;
            String[] temp = strLine.split(":");
            if(temp[0].contains("String")){
                PermissionNames.names[i] = remove(temp[0]);
            }
            PermissionNames.descriptions[i] = temp[1];

        }
        dataIO.close();
        fis.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to read from the SDCard or from resources within the project?

If you are trying to save this file on the SDCard then look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android).

Else if you are trying to read a file **not** in the SDCard then you will want to look at [this link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1522).

Answer (score 0):

yes it should give you exception, because you are trying to access a file that doesn't exists, if you have the file in your assets folder, then at first run copy it to your application path `getFilesDir()` then you can read it in the way you are doing.