# Read data from txt file present in sdcard of an Android device

Tags: android, file, file-manager

I want to read data from file:

```
    FileInputStream in = openFileInput(file);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
```

But I don't know "file". I want that the user tell me where the file is. I want to make him search the file with a filemanager. what should I do?
I hope I explained myself and sorry for the English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, you can find so many examples in the web

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
 String line;

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line);
    text.append('\n');
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
//You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```