# Store retrieve data (.txt) from SD card

Tags: android, search

Alright, here is my program and the problem:

My android app can take some texts and store it a local file. Lets say on an sd card. And it can categorize those file as well (create different folder, and save it there).

Now, my computer can run and write folders and `.txt` files, but I have no idea how to retrieve those in my list view. Let's say, my list view has two components, a `textView` and an `Imageview`, side by side. (And I want to retrieve those `.txt` files from my sd card, read a few words, and put them in the list in `textView`). You can consider it like a notepad with some features.

What I need to know now is how to read through all those data available in all of my sub-directories and put them in a list.(No need to explain about the `imageView` one, I can handle that, but want to know about `.txt`)

I know, I talk too much, but if you can guide me, I would really appreciate that.(Keep in mind that am still an amateur, so please explain the code you write or comment briefly)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to know how to get data from file it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2903404/1001401

If you need to know how to get list of files/directories in directory you can use this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Or you need a full mechanism? I think you can google it easily instead of waiting answer and crowd of angry programmers:)

Comment: And tutorial for listview: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/