# How to get selected xls file path from uri for SDK 17 or below for android?

Tags: java, android, getfiles

I need the solution for sdk version 17 or below

this is my method.

```
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String result = null;
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

i use this method but cursor value null return

help

Comment: look my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913001/pick-any-file-using-intent-in-android/45913122#45913122

Comment: Done i need only myuri.getPath();   no need this method

Comment: you get path at this line "Uri data = result.getData();"

Answer (score 2):

use my **FileSelector** :

**how to use** :

```
 new FileSelector(this, new String[]{FileSelector.XLS, FileSelector.XLSX}).selectFile(new FileSelector.OnSelectListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSelect(String path) {
        G.toast(path);
      }
    });


 new FileSelector(this, new String[]{".jpg", ".jpeg"}).selectFile(new FileSelector.OnSelectListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSelect(String path) {
        G.toast(path);
      }
    });
```

**source code** : (create class 'FileSelector' and copy/paste)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
 * Created by Javad on 2019-11-28 at 4:43 PM.
 */

public class FileSelector {

 private Activity context;
 private String[] extensions;
 private ArrayList<SelectedFile> itemsData = new ArrayList<>();
 public static final String MP4 = ".mp4", MP3 = ".mp3", JPG = ".jpg", JPEG = ".jpeg", PNG = ".png", DOC = ".doc", DOCX = ".docx", XLS = ".xls", XLSX = ".xlsx", PDF = ".pdf";


 public FileSelector(Activity context, String[] extensions) {
 this.context = context;
 this.extensions = extensions;
 }

 public interface OnSelectListener {
 void onSelect(String path);

 }

 public void selectFile(OnSelectListener listener) {
 String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 listOfFile(new File(sdCard));
 dialogFileList(listener);
 }

 private void listOfFile(File dir) {
 File[] list = dir.listFiles();

 for (File file : list) {
 if (file.isDirectory()) {
 if (!new File(file, ".nomedia").exists() && !file.getName().startsWith(".")) {
 Log.w("LOG", "IS DIR " + file);
 listOfFile(file);
 }
 } else {
 String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

 for (String ext : extensions) {
 if (path.endsWith(ext)) {
 SelectedFile selectedFile = new SelectedFile();

 selectedFile.path = path;
 String[] split = path.split("/");
 selectedFile.name = split[split.length - 1];
 itemsData.add(selectedFile);
 Log.i("LOG", "ADD " + selectedFile.path + " " + selectedFile.name);
 }
 }
 }
 }
 Log.d("LOG", itemsData.size() + " DONE");
 }

 private void dialogFileList(OnSelectListener listener) {
 LinearLayout lytMain = new LinearLayout(context);
 lytMain.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 lytMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 int p = convertToPixels(12);
 lytMain.setPadding(p, p, p, p);
 lytMain.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

 TextView textView = new TextView(context);
 textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 textView.setText("JDM File Selecor");

 RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(context);

 lytMain.addView(textView);
 lytMain.addView(recyclerView);

 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
 dialog.setContentView(lytMain);
 dialog.setCancelable(true);
 dialog.show();

 AdapterFile adapter = new AdapterFile(dialog, listener, itemsData);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
 LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
 }

 private int convertToPixels(int dp) {
 float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
 }

 private int screenWidth() {
 return context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
 }

 private class SelectedFile {
 public String path = "";
 public String name = "";
 }

 private class AdapterFile extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFile.ViewHolder> {

 private ArrayList<SelectedFile> itemsData;
 private OnSelectListener listener;
 private Dialog dialog;

 public AdapterFile(Dialog dialog, OnSelectListener listener, ArrayList<SelectedFile> itemsData) {
 this.itemsData = itemsData;
 this.listener = listener;
 this.dialog = dialog;
 }

 // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
 @Override
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
 linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 TextView txtName = new TextView(context);
 TextView txtPath = new TextView(context);
 txtPath.setTypeface(txtPath.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
 txtPath.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 11);

 linearLayout.addView(txtName);
 linearLayout.addView(txtPath);

 ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(linearLayout);
 return viewHolder;
 }

 // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

 public LinearLayout linearLayout;
 public TextView txtName;
 public TextView txtPath;

 public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
 super(itemLayoutView);

 linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView;
 txtName = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
 txtPath = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
 }
 }


 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
 return itemsData.size();
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
 final SelectedFile selectedFile = itemsData.get(position);

 viewHolder.txtName.setText(selectedFile.name);
 viewHolder.txtPath.setText(selectedFile.path);

 viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 dialog.dismiss();
 listener.onSelect(selectedFile.path);
 }
 });
 }
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will not work on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps), as access to external storage is restricted.

Comment: Permission RunTime can help : https://github.com/criss721/Android-Permission-RunTime

Comment: That will not help on Android 10 or higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Where I can find the solution to get the absolute path of file selected on Android 10 or higher?

Comment: @SwapnilKale: That is not possible. Not only is there no "absolute path", but you do not have access to the external storage filesystem anyway. Use the `Uri`, either directly or by copying the content to some file that you control.