# How get my file and read in android 4.4?

Tags: android

My application can read **xml** files, located on the **sdcard**. I read android artical:[External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/datastorage.html#AccessingExtFiles)
This artical said in **android 4.4** you can read just from your application folder so how can I get **xml** files when the user put it on **sdcard** and how I can I read it from that place.
Please give me an example or tutorial.

Here is the code, I currently have:

```
   File myInternalFile;
   String filepath = "plane";
   private String filename = "Pro.xml";
   String path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
   myInternalFile = new File(path, filename);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It changed a bit on KitKat but it remains possible to do it: the only difference is that you cannot store the data everywhere the sd card as they very well explained [there](http://lifehacker.com/android-kitkat-blocks-some-access-to-micro-sd-cards-1524997895). So if you want to store on sd card or read from sd card: look at this topic on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). And here is a more practical [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903404/2545832):