# Try to read text file from sdcard in other language

Tags: android

I try to read text file (file.txt) from SDcard and make string for Textview. so i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android) and every things works fine but when i changed language in text file , result is some question marks and not words .how can i fix this problem?

Comment: could an InputStream reader with the encoding overload constructor help?
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)
there is also a nice example here:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. this error fixed when you saved your .txt file as **UTF-8 Unicode**, not ANSI.